# Transformation of Lie Algebra By Modifying Generating Vector Fields

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus, vector-fields, jacobian

Let $U_1,\dots,U_k$ be $C^1$-vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to (0,\infty)$ be a $C^1$-function.  Let $Lie(U_i)$ denote the Lie algebra generated by $\{U_i\}_i=1^k$.  When is $dim(Lie(f\cdot U_i))=dim(Lie(U_i))$?

It's clear that, due to the assumption that $f$ is strictly positive, we have that
$$
dim\left(
\operatorname{span}\left\{
f U_i
\right\}_{i=1}^k
\right)
=
dim\left(
\operatorname{span}\left\{
U_i
\right\}_{i=1}^k
\right).
$$
When trying to compute the iterate Lie brackets, defined by:
$$
[fU_i,fU_j] := D(f U_i)fU_j - D(fU_j)fU_i, \qquad (1)
$$

Like in the above case, I'm thinking to reduce the iterated brackets with $f$ to those without.

**What I've Worked out**

---

From the [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector), we have that
$$
D(fU_i) = f D(U_i) + U_i\nabla f. \qquad (2)
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get that
$$
\begin{aligned}
[fU_i,fU_j] := & D(f U_i)fU_j - D(fU_j)fU_i
\\
= & (f D(U_i) + U_i\nabla f) (fU_j) - 
(f D(U_j) + U_j\nabla f) (fU_i) \\
= & f^2 D(U_i)U_j + fU_i\nabla f U_j - 
f^2 D(U_j)U_i - fU_j\nabla f U_i \\
= & (f^2) \underbrace{\left(D(U_i)U_j - D(U_j)U_i \right)}_{Part of  Lie(U_i)}
+ f\cdot \underbrace{\left(
U_i\nabla f U_j - U_j\nabla f U_i
\right)}_{???},
\end{aligned}
$$
here I use $\cdot$ to emphasise that $f$ is multiplying the quantity on its right and not applied to it!

What can be done with this term: $\left(
U_i\nabla f U_j - U_j\nabla f U_i
\right)$?

Comment: I reinterpreted your question as asking when the two lie algebras have the same dimension (since there is no reason why they should be "point-wise" the same).

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I meant to express.  Thanks!